# Pass variables to Partial views without using Session variable in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Basically i am handling two types of login. One is UserLogin, another One is Client login. I want to Separate these two. So i am passing session variable while login like the following,

// this is while login as a client

```
Session["LoginAs"] = "client";
```

//this is while login as a user

```
Session["LoginAs"] = "user";
```

But here one issue is there. Session is timed out within 2 minutes. If i increased in config file also same result only. So i don't want to pass these two into session. If any other option is available means it will be perfect.

Comment: take model property and pass to partial view instead of using session

Comment: i am passing variable only. here how can take model property?

Comment: then instead session take viewbag...

Comment: ok. But there is one issue. I am checking this session variable into some other partial view. Here can i use the viewdata from the controller? If i can do means my issue will be solve..

Comment: Consider creating a `CustomPrincipal` with an additional property (say `bool IsClient`) so that its stored in the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and is available for each request

Comment: yes use viewdata from controller ... i think your issue will be solved with this...

Comment: @PoliDev....Worked..???

Comment: ok. I am trying to do `bool IsClient`

Comment: I tried viewdata. but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Sessions getting reset due to application recycling. You should try using StateServer [session mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx).

However, the correct way of doing this using model. I would recommend you do do that.

```
        public class LoginModel {
            public bool IsClient { get; set; }
            public bool IsUser { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
            model.IsClient = true;

            return View(model);
        }
```

View

```
@model LoginModel
@if (Model.IsClient)
{
    //Client Login
}
else
{
    //User Login
}
```

**UPDATED**

Also, in order to identify login method in some other partial view.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.IsClient)
        {
            //Identify if Client Login and pass to some other partial view wich you need
            OtherPartialViewModel m = new OtherPartialViewModel();
            m.IsClient = true;
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```